# For long content, Is it possible to add 3 dots in the first line instead of the last line?

Tags: android, textview

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="734,324\nCoins"/>

Looks like this
⇩ ⇩ ⇩
734,324
Coins
```

---

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="183,238,928,819,348,184\nCoins"/>

Looks like this
⇩ ⇩ ⇩
183,238,928,819,
348,184...

I want it to be like this
⇩ ⇩ ⇩
183,238,928,819,34...
Coins
```

I want when the number of coins is long add 3 dots in the first line and keep coins word in the second line.

Comment: `android:ellipsize="middle"` will get you closer, but I don't know that it takes line breaks into account.

Comment: @CommonsWare unfortunately that is not working

Comment: Can you use two _TextViews_ with `android:ellipsize="end"` on the top one? Simplest solution IMO.

Comment: @Cheticamp I did that, Thanks